# How do I traverse all the nodes in a YAML tree in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, yaml

I am loading an arbitrary YAML document, and want to walk every node in the tree.  I don't know how nested the tree is beforehand, so I can't just use a simple each statement to walk all the nodes.

Here is how I'm loading the document:

```
tree = File.open( "#{RAILS_ROOT}/config/locales/es.yml" ){ |yf| YAML::load (yf)}
```

Comment: First off, let me tell you about YAML::load_file(path)

Comment: Do you at least know what the root node is? Hash? Array? Is there any format at all to the subsequent nodes or it all unknown? Can I assume that you want to traverse hashes and arrays, and that anything else is a leaf?

Comment: Can you post a sample yaml file to gist or pastie or somewhere and link it here? Also, can you give us an idea of what you want to do during the traversal? Act on the leaves?

Comment: (I'm assuming this file for now, which is all hashes: http://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/raw/master/rails/locale/es.yml)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
def traverse(obj, &blk)
  case obj
  when Hash
    # Forget keys because I don't know what to do with them
    obj.each {|k,v| traverse(v, &blk) }
  when Array
    obj.each {|v| traverse(v, &blk) }
  else
    blk.call(obj)
  end
end

traverse( YAML.load_file(filename) ) do |node|
  puts node
end
```

Edit:

Note that this only yields the leaf nodes. The question wasn't very clear as to what was wanted exactly.

Comment: sepp2k: the leaf nodes is exactly what I wanted, this is perfect!

Comment: added capacity to act on branches, and to pass parent node to block, based on @sepp2k great anaswer.

Answer (score 5):

Here is how to parse a YAML tree structure and to act on *each* node, branch and leaf. It also gives you parent of each node that you need, for example, when populating a database tree structure from your YAML file. It is a small addition to @sepp2k excellent answer:

```
require 'yaml'

def traverse(obj,parent, &blk)
 case obj
 when Hash
   obj.each do |k,v| 
     blk.call(k,parent)
     # Pass hash key as parent
     traverse(v,k, &blk) 
   end
 when Array
   obj.each {|v| traverse(v, parent, &blk) }
 else
   blk.call(obj,parent)
 end
end


# Example, creating a database tree structure, from your YAML file.
# Passing nil to root node(s) as parent

tree_str =<<EOF
  Regions:
    - Asia
    - Europe
    - Americas
  Other:
    - Foo:
      - bar
      - buz
EOF

traverse( YAML.load(tree_str), nil ) do |node,parent|
  puts "Creating node '#{node}' with parent '#{ parent || 'nil' }'"
end
```